# where to use isnull function

Tags: sql-server, pivot, isnull

I am using dynamic pivot scrip for my report. Below is my script.

```
   DECLARE @Columns VARCHAR(MAX)
set @Columns= ''

SELECT @Columns = @Columns + (QUOTENAME(RTRIM(LTRIM(cast(datename(month, [dates]) as char(15))))+',' + RTRIM(LTRIM(cast(year([dates]) as char(20))))) + ',') FROM efoxsfc.dbo.FTX_FA_Calender 
WHERE 1=1 
AND CAST(dates AS DATETIME) >= DATEADD(mm, -35 ,DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0,GETDATE()), 0)) 
AND dates <= DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0,GETDATE()), 0)

SET @Columns = LEFT(@Columns, LEN(@Columns) - 1)

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) 
set @SQL= ''
SET @SQL =
'WITH BaseData AS
(
     select 
        vendor_code,
        RTRIM(LTRIM(cast(datename(month, [CLOSED_DATE]) as char(15))))+'','' + RTRIM(LTRIM(cast(year([CLOSED_DATE]) as char(20)))) as [CLOSED_DATE],
        count(vendor_code) as [No. of Case] 
   from #teamp t WITH (NOLOCK)
      where 
       [CLOSED_DATE] is not null
  group by 
       vendor_code, CLOSED_DATE
)   
SELECT * 
FROM BaseData
PIVOT
(
    sum([No. of Case])
    FOR CLOSED_DATE IN (' +  @Columns + ')
) AS PivotTable'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL
```

where will be my isnull function so that will be replace null with zero.
Please advice !!

This is my new Print @SQL

```
   WITH BaseData AS
(
     select 
        vendor_code,
        RTRIM(LTRIM(cast(datename(month, [CLOSED_DATE]) as char(15))))+',' + RTRIM(LTRIM(cast(year([CLOSED_DATE]) as char(20)))) as [CLOSED_DATE],
        count(vendor_code) as [No. of Case] 
   from #teamp t WITH (NOLOCK)
      where 
       [CLOSED_DATE] is not null
  group by 
       vendor_code, CLOSED_DATE
)   
SELECT ISNULL([November,2012],0)AS[November,2012],ISNULL([December,2012],0)AS[December,2012],ISNULL([January,2013],0)AS[January,2013],ISNULL([February,2013],0)AS[February,2013],ISNULL([March,2013],0)AS[March,2013],ISNULL([April,2013],0)AS[April,2013],ISNULL([May,2013],0)AS[May,2013],ISNULL([June,2013],0)AS[June,2013],ISNULL([July,2013],0)AS[July,2013],ISNULL([August,2013],0)AS[August,2013],ISNULL([September,2013],0)AS[September,2013],ISNULL([October,2013],0)AS[October,2013],ISNULL([November,2013],0)AS[November,2013],ISNULL([December,2013],0)AS[December,2013],ISNULL([January,2014],0)AS[January,2014],ISNULL([February,2014],0)AS[February,2014],ISNULL([March,2014],0)AS[March,2014],ISNULL([April,2014],0)AS[April,2014],ISNULL([May,2014],0)AS[May,2014],ISNULL([June,2014],0)AS[June,2014],ISNULL([July,2014],0)AS[July,2014],ISNULL([August,2014],0)AS[August,2014],ISNULL([September,2014],0)AS[September,2014],ISNULL([October,2014],0)AS[October,2014],ISNULL([November,2014],0)AS[November,2014],ISNULL([December,2014],0)AS[December,2014],ISNULL([January,2015],0)AS[January,2015],ISNULL([February,2015],0)AS[February,2015],ISNULL([March,2015],0)AS[March,2015],ISNULL([April,2015],0)AS[April,2015],ISNULL([May,2015],0)AS[May,2015],ISNULL([June,2015],0)AS[June,2015],ISNULL([July,2015],0)AS[July,2015],ISNULL([August,2015],0)AS[August,2015],ISNULL([September,2015],0)AS[September,2015],ISNULL([October,2015],0)AS[October,2015]FROM BaseData
PIVOT
(
    sum([No. of Case])
    FOR CLOSED_DATE IN ([November,2012],[December,2012],[January,2013],[February,2013],[March,2013],[April,2013],[May,2013],[June,2013],[July,2013],[August,2013],[September,2013],[October,2013],[November,2013],[December,2013],[January,2014],[February,2014],[March,2014],[April,2014],[May,2014],[June,2014],[July,2014],[August,2014],[September,2014],[October,2014],[November,2014],[December,2014],[January,2015],[February,2015],[March,2015],[April,2015],[May,2015],[June,2015],[July,2015],[August,2015],[September,2015],[October,2015])
) AS PivotTable
```

This is my new Print @SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare another variable:

```
DECLARE @Columns2 VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
```

Then do the main thing:

```
SELECT @Columns2 = @Columns2 + 'ISNULL(' + (QUOTENAME(RTRIM(LTRIM(cast(datename(month, [dates]) as char(15))))+',' + RTRIM(LTRIM(cast(year([dates]) as char(20))))) + ', 0) AS ' + (QUOTENAME(RTRIM(LTRIM(cast(datename(month, [dates]) as char(15))))+',' + RTRIM(LTRIM(cast(year([dates]) as char(20))))) + ',') FROM efoxsfc.dbo.FTX_FA_Calender 
WHERE 1=1 
AND CAST(dates AS DATETIME) >= DATEADD(mm, -35 ,DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0,GETDATE()), 0)) 
AND dates <= DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0,GETDATE()), 0)

SET @Columns2 = LEFT(@Columns2, LEN(@Columns2) - 1)
```

Then use it like:

```
...
SELECT ' + @Columns2 + '
FROM BaseData
PIVOT
...
```

Comment: getting Incorrect syntax near '(' error where we are setting columns2 string

Comment: Before `EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL` do `print @SQL` and see generated code.

Comment: Please find the Print@SQL

Comment: What to find?? What's your problem?

Comment: its giving me Incorrect syntax near '('. error. trying to fix that..but no luck.

Comment: `ISNULL([November,2012], 0)` should go to select! columns2  to select. did you read my answer? I gave you example how to use columns2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93715/discussion-between-sony921-and-giorgi-nakeuri).

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding. After that i am getting Invalid column name. Please advice!!

Comment: See edits in my answer. How I construct columns2. Your aim is to get: `ISNULL([November,2012], 0) as [November,2012],ISNULL([December,2012], 0) AS [December,2012].... `

Comment: Corrected the @columns2 it showing the data properly in the month, but missing vendor_code in result.With the error Incorrect syntax near 'FROM BaseData

Comment: Are you kidding me? Add vendor to your select. Show generated statement.

Comment: I am trying to replay 0 with blank now.. so in isnull function  i replace 0 with blank but is not giving me the required output. Please advice !!

Comment: `is not working` tells me nothing. Show the statement and generated string and error.